# Can a true Christian continue to commit a particular sin? Like sin of porn watching

Tags: sin

Can a Christian commmmiit a particular sin and prays for forgiveness only to commit the same sin again? Will God forgive again if he asks for forgiveness Fromm God?

Comment: Related: [1 John Chapter 1 & 3 - Is there an apparent contradiction?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46/9289)

Comment: @Mr.Beatitude [But can't I just say one thing?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1588)

Comment: So, the single most important piece of advice I would give for dealing with a sin like pornography is also the only allowable advice on this site, so I'll say it: seek help from a trusted peer or pastor. Talk to them, get advice, get accountability.

Comment: if you want to choose a sin to live without worrying about it, no, but if you often fall into pornography seeking deliverance, yes, you are forgiven, but if you sin and only ask for forgiveness and live like that without seeking deliverance, you are running. an immense risk, I saw the testimony of a woman who was taken to hell to show where she would be if she died at that moment, she only masturbated once a month and was doomed.

Answer (score 3):

Let's state some general Christian principles on the subject of forgiveness. There are some minor variations in the approaches of different denominations, but nothing very serious.

1. **God's capacity for forgiveness is unlimited.** it's a doctrine of most churches, well supported by scripture, that God can and will forgive all sins that are truly repented, whether or not they are repeated. (For the one, very unlikely exception, search for "unforgivable sin" on this site.)
2. However **this does not give you permission to "ask for forgiveness" with the intention of repeating the sin**. Forgiveness involves repentance, means that you will attempt, to the best of your ability, not to repeat the sin.

Comment: Additionally, many Christian traditions, including mine, understand the unforgivable sin to be presumption or despair, in other words, the unwillingness to seek forgiveness, and not any unwillingness to forgive on God's part.

Comment: Exactly. No repentence = no forgiveness. You can't just say "I just beat off to porn but it's alright! I'm saved and forgiven". If you don't feel crushing guilt and a firm purpose of amendment you are doing it wrong and will go to Hell for being a presumptuous brat